# 40% are men, 30% drink only beer, 42% are women and drink not only beer

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I've got this question which I don't quite understand and am not sure what is asked of me, and how to approach it. I hope you can help out.

On a summer festival, 40% of all visitors are men, 30% drink only beer (Not sure here if it's meant 30% of the men, or 30% in general). Other than than it is known that 42% of the visitors are women and drink not only beer.

Provide a meaningful/useful Probability space ($\Omega, \Sigma, p $) for this information (Not sure either what is meant by this) and determine the value of $p$ for all elementary events. Furthermore, examine the following events for stochastic independence:  $R: $ "A randomly chosen visitor drinks only beer." and $W: $ "A randomly chosen visitor is a woman."

Any tips and help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: There isn't enough information here to do much with.  We can analyze $W$ since we are told the answer (the probability a random guest is a woman   is $1-.4=.6$).  But the independence of $R,W$ can't be analyzed as we are not told the gender distribution of the beer only crowd.

Comment: This is all the information I have...

Comment: Then you can't do the problem.  As you point out the information about the $30\%$ beer only crowd isn't complete.  Does that mean $30\%$ of the men?  Does it mean $30\%$ of the men and $30\%$ of the women?  Does it mean $30\%$ of the entire crowd?  These questions are more or less equivalent to the "independence" question and, based on the information we have, we can only guess.

Comment: It is basically how it's written. Would it be solvable if we knew if it was, say 30% of all visitors?

Comment: Your title says 32% ... should that be 30%?

Comment: You're right. It's 30%. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Well, yes and no.  In theory it helps but the numbers don't work out.  Since you tell us that $.68\%$ of the the women drink beer only (not a very likely result, by the way) then we already know that $.6\times .68=.408$ of the crowd are women who drink only beer.  Thus it can't be true that $30\%$ of the visitors are beer-only.

Comment: Note:  given my last comment, I should modify what I said earlier.  We can in fact state that $R,W$ are not independent.  If they were independent then we'd need $68\%$ of the men to be beer-only but then I can't come up with any interpretation of the $30\%$ that makes sense.

Comment: Hmm that is very strange. I mean I did have to translate this problem to English but I am pretty sure that I did so correctly.

Comment: @lulu also, could you explain what is meant by provide a meaningful probability space? I'm totally lost on that part.

Comment: Something feels wrong.  It seems highly unlikely that we are meant to reason along the lines of "well the $30\%$ is entirely undefined, but there's no sensible interpretation of it that seems consistent with independence so let's reject the hypothesis of independence."  The author should declare what the $30\%$ means without ambiguity.

Comment: @lulu based on the grammar of the text, I would assume that 30% of the men drink only beer, since it says: 
"40% of all visitors are men, 30% drink only beer." the two sentences are seperated by comas only and it doesn't say 30% of the visitors. I agree with you though it is very badly worded and very ambiguous.

Comment: Sure:  let's say that the $30\%$ means men only.  Then there are four relevant events, specifying the four types of guest:  $A$ is "beer only man".  we see that $P(A)=.4\times .3=.12$.  $B$ is "not beer only man" and $P(B)=.4-.12=.28$.  $C$ is "beer only woman" and $P(C)=.6\times .68=.408$ and $D$ is "not beer only woman" with $P(D)=.6-.408=.192$

Comment: So 40% are men.  Assuming a bi-gender exclusionary world, that means 60% are women.  42% percent are women who don't only drink beer (don't drink beer or drink other things as well as beer).  So 18% are women you drink only beer.  Given the wording I see no reason 30% refer to men.  So 30% drink only beer so 12% are men you drink only beer and so 22% are men who don't drink only beer.  So there is a 30% probability a visitor drinks only beer and a 60% chance it is a woman.  If we *do* assume it's 30% of the men who drink only beer... see next comment.

Comment: Correction:  I read the $42\%$ as the percent of women who don't drink beer only.  That was an error.  I'll post a (hopefully) correct computation below.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to rethink it as well my self now.

Answer (score 1):

In all cases we have that since 40% of festival goers are men, we have that 60% of festival goers are women. And since 42% of festival goers are women who don't drink only beer, you end up with 60-12= 18% of festival goers who are women who only drink beer. Note that this gives P(R|W)=30%

But as pointed out in the comments, there are 3 interpretations of the 30% claim:

A. 30% of the men drink only beer.

B. 30% of the festival goers are men who only drink beer

C. 30% of the festival goers drink only beer

So ... let's just work these out individually:

A. 40% of festival goers are men, 30% of whom drink only beer. Therefore, 12% of festival goers are men who drink only beer, and therefore 28% of festival goers are men who don't drink only beer. Note that $P(R|W) = P(R|W')$, so $R$ and $W$ are independent. Here is a picture:

[image]

B. 40% of festival goers are men, and 30% of the festival goers are men who only drink beer. That leaves 10% of festival goers who are men who don't drink only beer. Note that $P(R|W')=.75$, i.e. far more of the men drink only beer than the women do. So in this interpretation $R$ and $W$ are not independent. Picture:

[image]

C. 30% of the festival goers drink only beer. Since we already saw that 30% of the women drink only beer, that means that also 30% of the men only drink beer, and hence this scenario works out to be the same as scenario A (and thus $R$ are $W$ are independent again):

[image]

Comment: Would you elaborate the part where you got $P(R|W)=30%$ a bit please? How did you get the 30%?

Comment: @RudyAilabouni You know that 60% of the festival goers are women, since 40% are men. And you know that 42% of the festival goers are women who don't only drink beer, which is 70% of 60%, i.e. 70% of the women don;t only drink beer. Hence, 30% of the women drink only beer.

Comment: ah I see that makes sense. And thank you very much for the detailed answer above. Much appreciated.

Comment: @RudyAilabouni You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

Note:  the problem is worded in a somewhat ambiguous way and my comments above were, I believe, based on a misreading.  What follows assumes that the $30\%$ refers to the entire crowd.

There are $4$ types of guest:

$A$:  beer only men

$B$:  men who aren't beer only

$C$:  beer only women.

$D$: women who aren't beer only.

We want to compute the probability of each.

We are told that $$P(A)+P(B)=.4\quad \&\quad P(C)+P(D)=.6\quad \&\quad P(D)=.42$$

It follows at once that $$P(C)=.18$$

We are also told that $$P(A)+P(C)=.3$$ which implies that $$P(A)=.12\quad \&\quad p(B)=.28$$

To analyze independence, we remark that the probability that a guest is a beer drinking woman (given by $P(C)=.18$) is  the product of the probability that the guest is a woman and the probability that the guest drinks beer as that product is given by $$.6\times .3=.18$$

Thus we do have the desired independence.

Comment: Am I correct that if 30% applies only to the men (which grammatically I don't see why) the results would be the same as the 18% that are women who drink only beer represents 30% of the 60% who are women?  And if 30% of women and 30% of men drink only beer then 30% of everybody does.  And if 30% of women and 30% of total do then 30% of men do.  Correct?

Comment: @fleablood  Yeah, I'm going back and forth on that.  In what I wrote I assumed that the $30\%$ applied to the entire crowd.  That works out to neatly imply independence which makes me think it's what what is intended.

Comment: @fleablood  Oh, I see your point.  Yes.  If we assumed the $30\%$ applied just to men, then we'd get $P(A)=.4\times .3=.12$ just as we got with the supposedly different reading.   So, in point of fact, it might not make any difference how we read the $30\%$.  Weird.

Comment: Isn't that what independence means?  That the liklihood of being a beer only drinker will not be corelated to gender so the liklihood of men being beer drinking only will be the same as the liklihood of anyone being beer drinking only?

Comment: @fleablood  indeed it is, I just hadn't thought through the implication.  Still seems like a poor way to set a problem...defining things ambiguously in such a way that, seemingly by numerical accident, the ambiguities dissolve.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1:  30% of all visitors drink only beer.

Assuming strict bi-gender world:

40% men means 100- 40 = 60% women.

42% women who don't drink only beer means 60-42 = 18% women who drink only beer.

18% women who drink only beer means 30 - 18 = 12% men who drink only beer.

12% men who drink only beer means 40 - 12 = 28%  men who don't drink only beer.

So

Men who drink only beer: 12%

Men who don't drink only beer: 28%

Women who drink only beer: 18$

Women who don't drink only beer: 42%

Probability of a woman: 60%.  Probability of a person only drinking beer: 30%

Case 2: 30% of men drink only beer.  (I see nothing in the grammar to imply this)

40% men means 100- 40 = 60% women.

40% $\times$ 30% = 12% are men who drink only beer.

This means 40 -12 = 28% men who don't drink only beer.

42% women who don't drink only beer means 60-42 = 18% women who drink only beer.

So

Men who drink only beer: 12%

Men who don't drink only beer: 28%

Women who drink only beer: 18%

Women who don't drink only beer: 42%

Probability of a woman: 60%.  Probability of a person only drinking beer: 30%

Which is coincidentally the same result.

(As 18% being women who drink only beer is 30% of the 60% women.  So whether the 30% who only drink beer refers to men or to every body will be same as 30% of the women drink only beer.)

Comment: D'oh..  "coincidentally" means independence, I suppose.  If they weren't the same they wouldn't be independent.